# Why am I having issues with dangerouslySetInnerHTML if I return a string inside of a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React.

Within a map function in my `render`, I'm providing `prodID` as my argument, and that value is dynamic. When I attempt to pass that value into my function and return that value (the first, commented return), it sets the innerHTML correctly to my `ID`'s value. However, when I attempt to use that ID to actually find a different value within `forEach` and return that, no output is rendered.

I assume this is happening because `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is re-rendering the component before the `forEach` has completed?

```
getProductNameByID(id) {
    //return {__html: id};
    this.props.products.forEach(p => {
        if (p.id === id) {
            console.log(p.title);
            return {__html: p.title};
        }
    });
}

<li key={prodID} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getProductNameByID(prodID)} />
```

Comment: Returning from a foreach doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "Within a map function in my render..." You should show this context, especially so that we can see what `prodID` is.

Comment: Use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the matching product.

Comment: Why would you even need `dSIH` for this?

Comment: the duplicate answered my question. I was foolishly expecting the return in my `forEach` block to return in my `getProductNameByID`

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `return` is in a fat arrow function. It does **not** provide a return value for `getProductNameByID()`. `forEach()` does nothing with the return value from the callback function. Instead, you should use `map()`:

```
this.props.products.map(p => 
    <li key={p.id}>p.title</li>
);
```

Note that there is no need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.